# Getting ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

Tags: ruby

This is my code:

```
def random_card
  cards = ["two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven",
           "eight", "nine", "ten",
           "jack", "queen", "king", "ace"]

  cards[rand(13)]
end


def score(hand_score)
  random_card_numbers = {
    "two" => 2,
    "three" => 3,
    "four" => 4,
    "five" => 5,
    "six" => 6,
    "seven" => 7,
    "eight" => 8,
    "nine" => 9,
    "ten" => 10,
    "jack" => 10,
    "queen" => 10,
    "king" => 10,
    "ace" => 11
  }
  new_score = 0
  hand_score.each do |x|
     new_score += random_card_numbers[x]
  end
  new_score
end

def move(hand_score)
  while true do
    puts "Enter hit or stick"  
    user_input = gets.chomp
    if user_input == "hit" 
      hand_score.push(random_card)
      puts "Score so far: #{score(hand_score)}"
    elsif user_input == "stick"
      if score(hand_score) <= 21
        puts"You scored: #{score(hand_score)}"
      elsif score(hand_score) > 21
        puts "You busted with #{score(hand_score)}"
      end
      break
    end
  end
end

def run_game
  overall = []
  move(overall)
end
```

I get the following error when I run rspec with with the automated tests.
The program works fine but is not working with the automated tests. I looked at the parameters of move but dont quite understand why is it failing. I kinda think it is to do with the where I have put the while loops and if statements. If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

```
 Failure/Error: expect(move).to eq("hit") 
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
     # ./questions/question_1.rb:85:in `move'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! 
Method name `move` expects 1 argument, but you're passing no argument in this line - expect(move).to eq("hit")

Comment: Hi Im a bit confused arent I passing `overall` through `move` though?

Comment: Please add code for `./questions/question_1.rb` here or add github repository for your code here.

Comment: Please make sure to construct a [mre]. Note that all three of those words are important: it should be an *example* only, you should not post your entire actual code, rather you should create a simplified example that demonstrates your problem. Also, it should be *minimal*, i.e. it should not contain anything that is not absolutely required to demonstrate the problem. (Most beginner problems can be demonstrated in less than 5 short simple lines of code.) And it should be *reproducible*, which means that if I copy&paste and run the code, I should see the exact same problem you see.

Comment: In your case, you posted 49 lines of code, 48 of which have nothing to do with the problem, whereas you left out the *one line* which is actually relevant. https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: Im still a very beginner at coding so I dont really have an idea how to show a minimal example of this

Comment: Hey Johnny, the point of stackoverflow is not to just post a question and then delete it when you get an answer ... It's supposed to be used as a learning site for others and hopefully they will be able to see your question when having the same issue ... you can answer your own question if you want.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any such destructive edits will be reverted. Please see [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) for more information on how deleting content works on this site.

Answer (score 2):

In the `run_game` method you do you call `move` with the correct number of arguments. But your error comes from the line in the test:

```
expect(move).to eq("hit")
```

here you're calling `move` directly without arguments, hence the error